# How to avoid Illegal character in path with camel-hdfs?

Tags: java, apache-camel

I want to send local files to hdfs.

```
public class FileRouteBuilder extends EndpointRouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from(file("C://Users/pcn/Desktop/test").noop(true).recursive(true))
                .process(new FileProcessor())
                .to(hdfs("localhost:9000/2209212/"))
                .log(LoggingLevel.DEBUG, "completed");
    }
}
```

So, I wrote like this. But, when I used recursive option of file component, occured file path error.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in path at index 33: hdfs://localhost:9000/220922/rec\test4.txt
    at java.base/java.net.URI.create(URI.java:883)
    at org.apache.camel.component.hdfs.HdfsInfoFactory.newFileSystem(HdfsInfoFactory.java:102)
    at org.apache.camel.component.hdfs.HdfsInfoFactory.newHdfsInfoWithoutAuth(HdfsInfoFactory.java:63)
    at org.apache.camel.component.hdfs.HdfsInfoFactory.newHdfsInfoWithoutAuth(HdfsInfoFactory.java:41)
    at org.apache.camel.component.hdfs.HdfsOutputStream.createOutputStream(HdfsOutputStream.java:50)
    at org.apache.camel.component.hdfs.HdfsProducer.doProcess(HdfsProducer.java:205)
    at org.apache.camel.component.hdfs.HdfsProducer.process(HdfsProducer.java:188)
    at org.apache.camel.support.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:66)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendDynamicProcessor.lambda$process$0(SendDynamicProcessor.java:197)
    at org.apache.camel.support.cache.DefaultProducerCache.doInAsyncProducer(DefaultProducerCache.java:318)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendDynamicProcessor.process(SendDynamicProcessor.java:182)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.errorhandler.RedeliveryErrorHandler$SimpleTask.run(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:469)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor$Worker.schedule(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:187)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor.scheduleMain(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:64)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:184)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:398)
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.processExchange(GenericFileConsumer.java:492)
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.processBatch(GenericFileConsumer.java:245)
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.poll(GenericFileConsumer.java:206)
    at org.apache.camel.support.ScheduledPollConsumer.doRun(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:197)
    at org.apache.camel.support.ScheduledPollConsumer.run(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:111)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

because I'm working on Windows.
Then, I tried to change the path using Processor implements.

```
@Service
@Slf4j
public class FileProcessor implements Processor {

    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        GenericFile body = exchange.getIn().getBody(GenericFile.class);
        body.setEndpointPath(exchange.getIn().getBody(GenericFile.class).getEndpointPath().replace("\\/", "/"));
        body.setRelativeFilePath(exchange.getIn().getBody(GenericFile.class).getRelativeFilePath().replace("\\/", "/"));
        body.setAbsoluteFilePath(exchange.getIn().getBody(GenericFile.class).getAbsoluteFilePath().replace("\\/", "/"));

        exchange.getIn().setBody(body);

    }
}
```

But, it' doesn't work. I don't think sub folders paths from an `Exchange`, when I use recursive option.

How to fix it?

FYI, I set property and used `toD` too. But, result was the same.

Comment: Did you try changing  \  to / from paths?  i,e `.replace("\\", "/")`

Comment: You might also need to check if Camel File sets any of the [message headers](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.18.x/hdfs-component.html#_message_headers) used by camel hdfs. CamelFileName is probably what controls where camel hdfs stores the file so maybe modify it to use / instead of \. Quick recursive=true test resulted with `CamelFileName=sub\hmm.txt` header on windows so that might be it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to modify the relative path before injecting your file into HDFS, you can modify the header [`CamelFileName`](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.18.x/hdfs-component.html#_endpoint_header_CamelFileName) (that you can get from the constant `HdfsConstants.FILE_NAME`) to fit your requirements.

So in your case, your `Processor` could rather be something like:

```
public class FileProcessor implements Processor {

    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) {
        exchange.getIn().setHeader(
            HdfsConstants.FILE_NAME,
            exchange.getIn().getHeader(HdfsConstants.FILE_NAME, String.class)
                .replace('\\', '/')
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry to reply too late. I solved the problem the same way on that day. Thank you for your help.